# What happens when fgets encounters EOF in the middle of an input?

Tags: c

The man page says:

> fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.

I wrote a small C file which calls fgets to test its behavior. I particularly wanted to see what happens when EOF occurs after some characters have been inputted. I used the eof key combination (Ctrl+D) on bash. I had to press Ctrl+D twice for fgets to return. It printed out the characters inputted until I pressed Ctrl+D twice. Pressing Ctrl+D once after some characters had been inputted had no effect at all. If I inputted some characters after this they were stored in the passed array. Why does fgets behave this way?

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you want to learn about. Do you want to understand the behaviour of `fgets` or the typical behaviour of your terminal when you type Ctrl-D, and other control key combinations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior you describe has nothing to do with fgets.  The shell does not close the input stream until you press ctrl-D the 2nd time.

Comment: But fgets returns if I press Ctrl+D without inputting any characters previously. I don't need to enter it twice in that case.

Comment: ctrl-D is handled differently when there are no characters on the current line.  In that case, the first time it is keyed, it closes the stream.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29

Comment: While the behaviour is explained, I wonder what does happen if there is an eof encountered after a few characters have been input. Is there a good way to test this? Better yet, is there some place other than the man-page where this behaviour is properly and officially documented?

Comment: @batbrat: What's wrong with your man page documentation? Mine clearly says that they return the pointer passed in unless an error occurs or end of file occurs when _no_ characters have been read. I've checked in ISO/IEC 9899:1999 and I believe it's a faithful rewording of the description there.

Comment: @Charles Bailey, thank you for clearing that up. I'm sorry for the delayed response. As for the man-page thing, my memory fails me at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You should find that if the input ends after at least some characters were read but before a newline is encountered that `fgets` returns non-null (a pointer to the supplied buffer) and the supplied buffer won't contain a newline but will be null terminated.

This is just what the documentation for `fgets` says.

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[200];

    char* ret = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);

    printf("exit code = %p\n", (void*)ret);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("read code = %s<--END\n", buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
$ printf "no newline here->" | ./a.out
exit code = 0x7fff6ab096c0
read code = no newline here-><--END
```

or:

```
$ printf "newline here->\nmore text\n" | ./a.out
exit code = 0x7fff6f59e330
read code = newline here->
<--END
```

on no input:

```
$ printf "" | ./a.out
exit code = (nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just like reading from text file stored on disk that doesn't happen to have a new-line character at the end of the last line.  The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)'s description of `fgets()` specifies what it does, including in this case:

> `char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n,`
>        `FILE * restrict stream);`
>
> The **fgets** function reads at most one less than the number of
>   characters specified by **n** from the stream pointed to by **stream**
>   into the array pointed to by **s**. No additional characters are read
>   after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A
>   null character is written immediately after the last character read
>   into the array.

`fgets()` can give you a string without a new-line if the input line is too long to fit, or if there's no new-line before end-of-file.

When you're reading from a disk file, an end-of-file condition occurs when you reach the end of the file.  When you're reading from an interactive device such as a keyboard, the way an end-of-file condition is triggered is not specified by the C standard.  On Unix-like systems, it's triggered by typing <kbd>Control-D</kbd> at the beginning of a line, or by typing <kbd>Control-D</kbd> twice in the middle of a line (though the control character can be reconfigured).

Whether this is even possible depends on the implementation.

C99 7.19p2 says:

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into
>   lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a
>   terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a
>   terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.

Unix-like systems generally don't require the trailing new-line character.